# Using adverbial modifiers ("the whole day" vs "for the whole day")

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-constructions, adverbial-phrases, perfect-continuous

I found information that claims natives prefer to say `"the whole day"` rather than `"for the whole day"`. Since then, I've been wondering what the situations are in which a speaker is more likely to say `"for the whole day"`? The variant isn't incorrect, so are there any situations in which it is needed?

I assume we use `"the whole day"` to indicate only the period of time, something like having experienced something for a period of time.
And the second phrase `("for the whole day")` implies something that the person wants to draw attention to as an ongoing action or situation. For example, a recent graduate gets a job and is proud of it, is proud of how much time it has taken.

```
"I have been developing our summer photos the whole day".
```

Am I right? I would be very grateful if you could give me some examples.

Comment: You need to provide a context. It cannot be decided without a full sentence, since both are valid in different contexts.

Comment: @Lambie, this context.

Comment: Though *all the day* is not exactly incorrect, it's much more common to say *all day*.

Comment: They mean the same thing and although I could go through a grammatical explanation, is it worth it? Think of FOR and SINCE with work: work for three days, work for two hours. versus: work a/one day, work a/one week. whole can also be entire. But the word whole doesn't make the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ***the whole day*** and ***for the whole day*** are correct in the following sentences and they essentially mean the same thing.

> I would be tired ***for*** the whole day.
>
> She was silent *the whole day*.

Both ***the whole day*** and ***for the whole day*** here mean that *throughout the period of a complete day*.

Some select Noun Phrases (NP), and they are very limited in number, can act as a time adjunct. ***the whole day*** is one of them. So in this case, it doesn't matter, for a time adjunct whether you use the bare NP, or a Preposition Phrase with the same NP as the complement of a head preposition (for example: *for the whole day*).

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov you're welcome :-) happy to help!